# modify Istio access log format with json output

Tags: kubernetes, istio

How to modify istio meshconfig access log format when the output accessLogEncoding set to JSON, changing the format as [describe on the docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/) didn't work.

```
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    accessLogEncoding: JSON
    accessLogFormat: '[%START_TIME%] \"%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%\" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %RESPONSE_CODE_DETAILS% %CONNECTION_TERMINATION_DETAILS%\"%UPSTREAM_TRANSPORT_FAILURE_REASON%\" %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION% %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% \"%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%\" \"%REQ(USER-AGENT)%\" \"%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%\" \"%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%\" \"%UPSTREAM_HOST%\" %UPSTREAM_CLUSTER% %UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS% %REQUESTED_SER'
```

Answer (score 9):

It works!, This is what i needed:

```
spec:
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: /dev/stdout
    accessLogEncoding: JSON
    accessLogFormat: |
      {
        "protocol": "%PROTOCOL%",
        "upstream_service_time": "%REQ(x-envoy-upstream-service-time)%",
        "upstream_local_address": "%UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS%",
        "duration": "%DURATION%",
        "upstream_transport_failure_reason": "%UPSTREAM_TRANSPORT_FAILURE_REASON%",
        "route_name": "%ROUTE_NAME%",
        "downstream_local_address": "%DOWNSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS%",
        "user_agent": "%REQ(USER-AGENT)%",
        "response_code": "%RESPONSE_CODE%",
        "response_flags": "%RESPONSE_FLAGS%",
        "start_time": "%START_TIME%",
        "method": "%REQ(:METHOD)%",
        "request_id": "%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%",
        "upstream_host": "%UPSTREAM_HOST%",
        "x_forwarded_for": "%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%",
        "client_ip": "%REQ(True-Client-Ip)%",
        "requested_server_name": "%REQUESTED_SERVER_NAME%",
        "bytes_received": "%BYTES_RECEIVED%",
        "bytes_sent": "%BYTES_SENT%",
        "upstream_cluster": "%UPSTREAM_CLUSTER%",
        "downstream_remote_address": "%DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS%",
        "authority": "%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%",
        "path": "%REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)%",
        "response_code_details": "%RESPONSE_CODE_DETAILS%"
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! Respect. This should be in docs of Istio, since this is needed for production grade.

Answer (score 0):

While using istioctl (ISTIO_VERSION =1.20.3), the following command worked for me:

```
istioctl install --set profile=default -y --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout --set meshConfig.accessLogFormat="{\"protocol\":\"%PROTOCOL%\",\"upstream_service_time\":\"%REQ(x-envoy-upstream-service-time)%\",\"upstream_local_address\":\"%UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS%\",\"upstream_remote_address\":\"%UPSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS%\",\"duration\":\"%DURATION%\",\"request_duration\":\"%REQUEST_DURATION%\",\"request_tx_duration\":\"%REQUEST_TX_DURATION%\",\"response_tx_duration\":\"%RESPONSE_TX_DURATION%\",\"response_duration\":\"%RESPONSE_DURATION%\",\"roundtrip_duration\":\"%ROUNDTRIP_DURATION%\",\"upstream_transport_failure_reason\":\"%UPSTREAM_TRANSPORT_FAILURE_REASON%\",\"route_name\":\"%ROUTE_NAME%\",\"downstream_local_address\":\"%DOWNSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS%\",\"user_agent\":\"%REQ(USER-AGENT)%\",\"response_code\":\"%RESPONSE_CODE%\",\"response_flags\":\"%RESPONSE_FLAGS%\",\"start_time\":\"%START_TIME%\",\"method\":\"%REQ(:METHOD)%\",\"request_id\":\"%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%\",\"upstream_host\":\"%UPSTREAM_HOST%\",\"x_forwarded_for\":\"%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%\",\"client_ip\":\"%REQ(True-Client-Ip)%\",\"requested_server_name\":\"%REQUESTED_SERVER_NAME%\",\"bytes_received\":\"%BYTES_RECEIVED%\",\"bytes_sent\":\"%BYTES_SENT%\",\"upstream_cluster\":\"%UPSTREAM_CLUSTER%\",\"downstream_remote_address\":\"%DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS%\",\"authority\":\"%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%\",\"path\":\"%REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)%\",\"response_code_details\":\"%RESPONSE_CODE_DETAILS%\"}"
--set meshConfig.enableEnvoyAccessLogService=true --set meshConfig.accessLogEncoding=JSON
```